# How can I convert multiple coordinates to visual route?

Tags: routes, gps, converters

How can I convert a dozen of coordinates into a route-line ? Is there a site or a way to paste on google maps ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [Directions Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) for that purpose. Below example shows how to read coordinates and print a route in Google Maps:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#textCoordinates").val());  //read coordinates from textarea element      
var converter = new GPSMapConverter();
converter.printRoute(data);
```

where

coordinates are provided in the following JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "lat": 41.879676,
    "lng": -87.632599
  },
  {
    "lat": 39.908601,
    "lng": -86.149237
  },
  {
    "lat": 40.009653,
    "lng": -83.012640
  },
  {
    "lat": 40.440311,
    "lng": -79.990691
  },
  {
    "lat": 38.979612,
    "lng": -77.008612
  }
]
```

and `GPSMapConverter`:

```
var GPSMapConverter = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.9865525, 25.40965)
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
};

GPSMapConverter.prototype = {

    clearRoute: function() {
        if (this.directionsDisplay != null) {
            this.directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        }
    },

    printRoute: function(coordinates) {
        var directionWaypoints = $.map(coordinates, function(coord, i) {
            if (i > 0 && i < coordinates.length - 1) {
                return {
                    "location": new google.maps.LatLng(coord.lat, coord.lng),
                    "stopover": false
                };
            }
        });


        var request = {
            origin: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0].lat, coordinates[0].lng),
            destination: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[coordinates.length - 1].lat, coordinates[coordinates.length - 1].lng),
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            waypoints: directionWaypoints
        };
        this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(request);
    },

    calculateAndDisplayRoute: function (request) {
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

        (function(display,service) {
            service.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    display.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                }
            });
        })(this.directionsDisplay, this.directionsService);
    }
};
```

Source code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RNQ8cNfLjQfbo3gZu4y4?p=preview)

Live example: [App](https://d157rqmxrxj6ey.cloudfront.net/vgrem/18228/)